# Organizing Plots in Seaborn Pairplot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I've got a pandas dataframe with a bunch of values in and I want to plot each axis against each axis to get plots of every column against one another. Furthermore, I'm having an issue of the values of my y axis being so condensed that's it's unreadable. I've tried changing the height but have no clue how to "clean up" this axis.

[image: Dataframe with all my data in]

Here is my plotting code:

```
import seaborn as sns
grid = sns.pairplot(df_merge, dropna = True, height=1.5)
```

Then here is the graph that has been plotted.

[image: Seaborn plot of my dataframe]

Comment: Looks like your data might be strings and need to be converted into numbers

Comment: Yup this was exactly what the issue was! Cheers